# Regex that picks up words separated by hashtags

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a Regex that picks up text that is separated by hashtags:

```
wordWORD#WORD#WORD
```

So far I have this Regex that works partially. Not sure how to not include the lower case ‘word’ out of my match and only include WORD#WORD#WORD

```
([a-zA—Z0-9]+,?)#([a-zA-Z0-9]+,?)#([a-zA-Z0-9])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: As a side note, the second hyphen in the first character class should also be like this `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: The first `WORD` is not a hashtag.  Why do you want to include it.

Comment: I’m wanting it to include that in my regex :)

Comment: If you use the right hyphen it works right? https://regex101.com/r/iMVZwl/1 There are no comma's, you might omit the `,?` Or `([A-Z0-9]+)#([A-Z0-9]+)#([A-Z0-9]+)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird your regex works with the hyphens but how do I omit the lower case ‘word’

Comment: @user3683976 See the second pattern https://regex101.com/r/78x4uv/1 You could omit matching lowercase chars in that case

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird. That regex worked perfect. That was the missing piece from my regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* what you want is much [simpler](https://regex101.com/r/ebSh0c/1):

```
[A-Z\#]+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 3 capture groups without the a-z in the character class to not match lowercase characters. There is no comma in the example data, so you could omit `,?`

**Note** that you are not using a hyphen `-` in the first character class, but `—` (Em Dash)

<sup>(See the "Em Dash" https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2014)</sup>

You could update the pattern to:

```
([A-Z0-9]+)#([A-Z0-9]+)#([A-Z0-9]+)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/78x4uv/1).